# Is it possible to install mysqlclient (DB API driver) without using pip and PyPI?

Tags: django, python-3.x, driver, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I've been learning Python. I've installed Mysql database downloaded from the official website.I have Django framework installed through downloading it from the official website https://www.djangoproject.com/download/. Now I need mysqlclient (DB API driver). I've learned of possible security risks as to using pip and PyPI.

> The widely used pip package management system, which most Python
>   developers rely on, doesn't require cryptographic signature before
>   executing code when a package is installed.

PyPI is a third party repository. According to PyPI officials ([the article as of 9/16/2017](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/09/devs-unknowingly-use-malicious-modules-put-into-official-python-repository/)),

> PyPI does not have any full time staff devoted to it. It is a
>   volunteer run project with only two active administrators. As such, it
>   doesn't currently have resources for some of the proposed solutions
>   such as actively monitoring or approving every new project published
>   to PyPI.

On Septermber 16, 2017, there came some news about some Malicious Libraries uploaded into PyPI.
My question is how to install [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient)  needed in the context of Python, Django and Mysql database, without using pip and PyPI repository?

Answer (score 1):

This is *entirely* the wrong way to interpret that warning. If `pip` is unsafe, then installing random libraries directly will certainly not be any more safe. Use pip.

Comment: So far I've installed packages taken from the official websites. Is it unsafe? Could you explain why? I think they ensure better control over their packages provided in their websites.

Comment: While `pip` could be safer, Daniel's comment is true. You can do a lot of verification by reading the installation instructions on the site of the publisher. For example, Django's website says to install using `pip install Django` - they control the `Django` namespace on PyPI. I trust the Django documentation to install. You can also find the source of most of these projects on GitHub of BitBucket, if you wish to do further investigation.